# Java program to sort the elements of left/primary diagonal of an array using a bubble sort technique. Showing java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, arrays

```
  import java.util.*;
  class diag
  {
    void main()
    {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner (System.in);
        int m,i,j,tmp=0;
        System.out.println("Enter size of the array");
        m=sc.nextInt();
        int arr[][]=new int[m][m];
        int arr2[]=new int[m];
        System.out.println("Enter the elements");

        for(i=0;i<m;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<m;j++)
            {
                arr[i][j]=sc.nextInt();
            }
        }
        
        for(i=0;i<m;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<m;j++)
            {
                if(i==j)
                arr2[i]=arr[i][j];
            }
        }
        
        for(i=0;i<(m-1);i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<(m-i-1);j++);
            {
                if(arr2[j+1]<arr2[j])
                {
                    tmp=arr2[j];
                    arr2[j]=arr2[j+1];
                    arr2[j+1]=tmp;
                }
            }
        }
        
        System.out.println("Sorted elements of the diagonal--");
        for(i=0;i<m;i++)
        System.out.print(arr2[i]+ " ");
    }

}
```

`Index 2 out of bounds for length 2`
`at diag.main(diag.java:35)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What causes a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and how do I prevent it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it)

Comment: the error message seems clear enough. What is your question about it?

Comment: Which line is line 35 ?

Comment: `for(j=0;j<(m-i-1);j++);` ?

Comment: @fbiopen_up it's impossible for that being line 35

Comment: @Stultuske It might not be but it's incorrect.

Comment: Indeed, it shouldn't have a ;, but that line isn't causing the current issue.

Comment: @Stultuske well, i'm afraid it might be causing that issue. since the condition in that `for` loop will be ignored

Comment: .. Might indeed have an impact. But looking at the rest of the code, honestly doesn't make all that much sense to me considering the expected output and what I think 'll be printed.